# Vector securely erasing its memory

Tags: c++, security

I need to create a secure, self cleaning memory buffer, that leaves no traces of its content behind in memory when being cleared or going out of scope.

My example code shows a comparison between my first experimental vectorc and the std::vector. You can see in the output, that vectorc overwrites its memory when calling clear() while the content of the std::vector is still accessible after clear().

I fear that the compiler may optimize away the memory overwriting in some cases, if the memory is no longer accessed after clear() or going out of scope (destructor). Is using volatile valid, like in the line commented out in clear()? The memset() does not like volatile void*, so I had to cast it away again. There must be a better way of doing this.

I know that a growing vector and a resize may leave content behind, as the memory block may be moved to a different location, but let's ignore this point to keep the example short.

I access memory behind size() up to the capacity(). This may lead to undefined behavior, or is it okay the way I do it?

Any thoughts on the topic? Any better solutions?

vectorc.cpp:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T> class vectorc : public std::vector<T>
{
  public:

  ~vectorc()
  {
    clear();
  }

  void clear()
  {
    // volatile T* ptr = std::vector<T>::data(); ???
    T* ptr = std::vector<T>::data();
    memset((void*)ptr, 0, std::vector<T>::capacity()); // May have been shrinked, so size may leave memory behind?!
    std::vector<T>::clear();    
  }
};

void printmem(const std::vector<char>& v)
{
   const char* ptr = v.data();
   std::cout << "capacity=" << v.capacity() << ", size=" << v.size() << ", content=\"";
   for(size_t i = 0; i < v.capacity(); ++i, ++ptr)
     std::cout << *ptr;
   std::cout << "\"" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << "start" << std::endl;

  std::cout << "vectorc:" << std::endl;
  {
    vectorc<char> vs;
    vs.push_back('s');
    vs.push_back('e');
    vs.push_back('c');
    vs.push_back('r');
    vs.push_back('e');
    vs.push_back('t');

    printmem(vs);
    vs.clear();
    printmem(vs);
  }
  // vs went out of scope and I want all it's allocated memory set to zero.

  std::cout << "std::vector:" << std::endl;
  {
    std::vector<char> vp;
    vp.push_back('p');
    vp.push_back('u');
    vp.push_back('b');
    vp.push_back('l');
    vp.push_back('i');
    vp.push_back('c');

    printmem(vp);
    vp.clear();
    printmem(vp);
  }

  std::cout << "end" << std::endl;
}
```

Compile and run:

```
g++ vectorc.cpp
./a.out
```

Output:

```
start
vectorc:
capacity=8, size=6, content="secret"
capacity=8, size=0, content=""
std::vector:
capacity=8, size=6, content="public"
capacity=8, size=0, content="public"
end
```

Comment: Forget the vector derivation. Just write an allocator and have it wipe the memory after content-destruction, then use that allocator on *every* container whose memory  backdrop you want erased.

Comment: @WhozCraig that's not trivial. Could you give some hints/links/sources

Comment: Please try to focus on one specific issue / question. "Any thoughts on the topic?" is a good indication that your quesiton is too broad

Comment: @JHBonarius its surprisingly easier than you may think. The only wtf someone may first  experience is how the rebind concept works. cppreference has  a [nice writeup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator) on user-defined allocators, including a trivial example to start with. At least that's where I learned them. YMMV.

Comment: Crypto++ has containers that clean up their memory. If you look in its source-code it contains a warning, which goes (out of my head) _beware that this may actually **not** clean up its memory after destruction, because memsetting to all zeroes may get optimized away by the compiler_.

Comment: `I need to create a secure, self cleaning memory buffer, that leaves no traces of its content behind in memory when being cleared or going out of scope.` this might not be possible to be solved in a protable way. While it is possible to create custom allocators to clean the memory that is currently manged by the vector (also in the resize case), you still might leave traces because the system itself could move the memory itself (e.g. swap files, memory compression, …) which is out of your control if you use only functionalities provided by the std library itself.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I tried the allocator thing and it seems to do the trick with the memory. But with an explicit given allocator I can no longer call functions like my printmem(), as it expects a const ref to a standard vector and my compiler no longer converts it, like it did with the derived version. What am I missing?

Comment: Its a good question. You can either retool your printmem to be a template, taking generic iterators (e.g. `template<class Iter> void printmem(Iter beg, Iter end)`, and pass your vector iterators, or if you *really* want to go down an interesting road you can write a generic variadic template edition [that looks something like this](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d26158a45c113c5), at which point you can just pass your container with your custom allocator and it should work. (it will also work with damn near any sequence container, with or without your custom allocator).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since search engines seems to always put this question on top of their results for secure erasing of std::vector memory, it will be helpful if there is an answer with the solution even if the comments already indicate the use of custom allocator.

So below is an implementation that uses a custom allocator that extends the standard std::allocator class by providing secure erazing of memory upon deallocation. It is actually based on a blog post that predates OP question by 3 years: https://blog.noser.com/securely-deallocate-a-stdvector-or-a-stdstring/

```
// Secure erazing of memory macro for Windows and non-Windows systems
#if defined(_WIN32)
#include <windows.h>
#define secure_zeromem(mem,size) do { RtlSecureZeroMemory (mem, size); } while (0)
#else
#define secure_zeromem(mem,size) do { volatile char *burnm = (volatile char *)(mem); int burnc = size; while (burnc--) *burnm++ = 0; } while (0)
#endif


template <class T>
class SecureAllocator
    : public std::allocator<T>
{
public:
    template<class U> struct rebind
    {
        typedef SecureAllocator<U> other;
    };

    SecureAllocator() throw()
        : std::allocator<T>()
    {

    }

    SecureAllocator(const SecureAllocator& other) throw()
        : std::allocator<T>(other)
    {

    }

    template <class U> SecureAllocator(const SecureAllocator<U>& other) throw()
        : std::allocator<T>(other)
    {

    }


    void deallocate(T* ptr, std::size_t n) {
        if (ptr != nullptr && n > 0) {
            secure_zeromem(ptr, n * sizeof(T));
        }
        std::allocator<T>::deallocate(ptr, n);
    }
};

typedef std::vector<unsigned char, SecureAllocator<unsigned char> > SecureVector;
typedef std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, SecureAllocator<char> > SecureString;
```

Comment: This answer could be improved tremendously by including some of the other platform specific and standard library solutions for securely setting memory before defaulting to the archaic and fiddly `volatile` pointer solution.

Answer (score 1):

The standard implementation of `std::vector`'s destructor and `clear()` member function does not guarantee that the container leaves no traces of its content, but requires that the destructors of the elements are called. Furthermore, it is neither possible to use a custom allocator with a `deallocate()` member function that cleans the memory before deallocating it as the `clear()` member function does not guarantee that the underlying buffer is deallocated.

You should implement the custom allocator in order that the `destroy()` member function perform the clean operation. In your case, it should assign a value-initialized object of type `T` to the pointed-to object before calling the destructor.

If you want to avoid compiler's optimizations, you can always use the `volatile` keyword, even if he compiler will difficulty optimize a function like `std::memset()`. And if you do not want to use it, there are no many alternatives. For example, the standard algorithm `std::fill()` is often optimized into the below function if the passed iterators are not marked as `volatile`.

Comment: This still does not answer the central question though: How can I implement the cleaning of memory in a way that the compiler is not going to optimize it out? The cleanup in custom class constructors you recommend faces the exact same problem as Op's custom `vector` destructor does in the question.

Comment: It is not the central question though: many things were asked the question, and the biggest is about a way that guarantees to leave no traces of the content behind in memory when being cleared or going out of scope, as the title says ___Vector securely erasing its memory___.